# Read batch of images is very slow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code, which is reading a batch of 10 images from files on my local disk.

The problem is that the code seems to run very slow. It takes about 5-6 minutes to run to completion. The directory containing the images contains approx. 25.000 images.

Is the code correct or have I done something stupid?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

image_width  = 202
image_height = 180
num_channels = 3

filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once("./train/Resized/*.jpg")

def read_image(filename_queue):
    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, image_filename = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_filename)
    image.set_shape((image_height, image_width, 3))

    return image

def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
    input_image = read_image(filename_queue)
    min_after_dequeue = 10000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    image_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [input_image], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    return image_batch

new_batch = input_pipeline(filenames, 10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Required to get the filename matching to run.
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    # Coordinate the loading of image files.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    b1 = sess.run(new_batch)

    # Finish off the filename queue coordinator.
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: You could time each function call that you suspect to be the culprit in order to narrow down the problem, e.g. time `image_reader.read(..)` and `tf.image.decode_jpeg(..)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce min_after_dequeue to 1000 and try once. Look at the following timelines for different min_after_dequeue values.

[min_after_dequeue = 2000 => 2.1 sec to finish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTCEw.png)

[min_after_dequeue = 100  => 0.13 sec to finish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M0Pc.png)

Do following to get timelines

```
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

b1 = sess.run(new_batch,options=run_options,run_metadata=run_metadata)
# Create the Timeline object, and write it to a json
tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
with open('timelinestack1.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(ctf)
```

Also, make sure all of your images have same size as you mentioned. Otherwise, use below line before set_shape().

```
image = tf.image.resize_images(imaged, [224, 224])
```

I hope I gave a reasonable answer.

Comment: Thanks, reducing min_after_dequeue to 1,000 reduces execution time significantly. So, if I understand this correctly to return a batch of 10 images, actually min_after_dequeue number of images are read. Then 10 images are drawn randomly from those. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it's better to limit min_after_dequeue value depending on your batch size.